# Arithmetic operations evaluation in GWT

Tags: gwt

Is there any library / module for simple arithmetic operations evaluation for GWT?

For example, some method which could transform string "14 + (28 * 10)" to 294?

I know, that there's [arity](http://code.google.com/p/arity/) for Java. I need something more lightweight which would work in GWT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript's eval should be adequate. Using JSNI from your Java code:

```
public void test() {
    double result = calculate("14 + (28 * 10)");
}

public final native double calculate(String op) /*-{
    return eval(op);
}-*/;
```